# How do I display a different text after a particular number of seconds?

Tags: android

I am trying to display a different text after 3 seconds, like the iPhone does where it greets you in different languages, like Hello, Hola, Bonjour, etc.

How do I do this in android studio?
I tried creating an array list and a timer but nothing seems to work

Comment: You can use a CountDownTimer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this piece of code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //show your message
        Toast.makeText(context,"hello",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
},3000);
```